# How to extract data from a facebook game

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to extract data from an existing Facebook game such as Total Domination.
I want to get data such as how many troops I have etc into a spreadsheet automatically.
If it is possible, how can I do it, or where should I find out?

Answer (score 2):

No, game information is not part of Facebook. It is stored on the game own server. The content of an app is private. Only the developer of the game decides how the data is displayed or shared.

The [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/) only furnishes information about the app properties like name, description, icon, url, developers, etc.

Comment: Thank you Stephane, thats put an end to that.